# Why does my PHP-generated .ICS file open in a text editor?

Tags: php, icalendar

I'm using PHP to generate and save a .ICS file to the server, which is then attached to an email as an attachment and sent to the user.

The code generating the .ICS file (missing some context since its part of a larger object, but the gist of it):

```
public function ics() {
    $ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" .
        "VERSION:2.0\n" .
        "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\n" .
        "PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN\n" .
        "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" .
        "UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "\n" .
        "DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd') . 'T' . gmdate('His') . "\n" .
        "DTSTART:" . CrRequest::dateToCal(strtotime($this->cdate . " " . $this->start_time)) . "\n" .
        "DTEND:" . CrRequest::dateToCal(strtotime($this->cdate . " " . $this->end_time)) . "\n" .
        "SUMMARY:" . $this->location . "\n" .
        "END:VEVENT\n" .
        "END:VCALENDAR\n";

    $name = 'i' . $this->id . 'send.ics';
    file_put_contents(self::$icslocation . $name, $ical);
    return $name;
}
```

And an example of the text being generated:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:<summary>
LOCATION:<location>
DTSTART:20170824T070000
DTEND:20170824T104500
DESCRIPTION:
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

A complaint that I've received is that the .ICS file opens in a plain text editor. My gut reaction is to say there's nothing I can do about that - that the user needs to configure their system to open .ICS files in the correct application. However, *am* I missing something in the file creation? Is this one of those unfortunate issues that *must* be handled on the user's end, or can I do something additional here to direct their system to open it in an email application?

Comment: It seems to be a user issue. I just ran the code on my machine and the .ics file opened on iCal without a problem. I think another way to test this is to send the user an ICS file you *know* opens on your calendar software correctly and check if they can open it correctly.

Comment: Hmmm - the interesting thing, is that when I open it directly from the email, it opens as plaintext. However, if I make a new .ics file, paste the content in, save it to the desktop, and open it from there - it works fine.

Comment: Are you setting the correct MIME type (text/calendar) when you add the file as an attachment to the email?

Comment: Are you sending the email from PHP? Or is PHP just generating the file and then being sent via something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the users browser's settings for what to do with a filetype and yes as Rob suggested the filetype will be determined by the mime type, so just creating a text file with ics data in it is not adequate.  It must have a mime type of 'text/calendar'  AND the user's browser must be set to open whatever calendar application they use.